# How to return the row with the data all are NULL if an empty result set?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I return the row with the data all are NULL if MYSQL returns an empty result set?

`article` table with this data,

```
id     title     url
1      abc       abc
```

Query,

```
SELECT*
FROM article
WHERE id = '2'
```

Result,

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 sec)
```

Result I need,

```
id     title     url
NULL   NULL      NULL
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Only with tricks. Do you really need it?

Comment: Yes please. Would love to see how the trick works thanks.

Comment: Why not just check the row count in PHP? Show your PHP where you need that kind of stuff.. You can select that with UNION. but i can't imagine why that would be necessary??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t2.*
from (select 1) t1 left join
article t2 on t2.id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM article
 WHERE id = '2'
union all
select null, null, null
  from dual
 where not exists (select 1 from article where id = '2')
```